# $3$ doesn't divide $x\Longrightarrow\;x^3\equiv\pm1 (\operatorname{mod}9)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck in this elementary problem: how can I show that $3$ doesn't divide $x$ implies $\;x^3\equiv\pm1 (\operatorname{mod}9)\:$?

Thanks a lot

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ 3\nmid x\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid x\pm1\,\Rightarrow\,3^2\mid x^3\pm1 $ by below, with $\,p = 3,\ y = \mp 1$
$\tag*{}$
**Lemma** $\ $ Prime $\,p\mid x-y\,\Rightarrow\,p^2\mid x^p-y^p$
$\tag*{}$
**Proof** $\ $ Note $\ x^p-y^p = (x-y)(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}y+\cdots xy^{p-2}+y^{p-1})\ $ and, mod $\,p,\,$ because $\,y \equiv x\,$ the second factor above is $\,\equiv x^{p-1}+x^{p-1}+\cdots x^{p-1}+x^{p-1}\equiv p\, x^{p-1}\equiv 0.$
$\tag*{}$
**Remark** $\ $ The Lemma generalizes to the widely used [Lifting the Exponents (LTE) Lemma](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $3\nmid x, x=3a\pm1$ where $a$ is any integer

$$\implies x^3=(3a\pm1)^3=(3a)^3+3(3a)^2(\pm1)+3(3a)(\pm1)^2+(\pm1)^3\equiv\pm1\pmod9$$

Comment: Nicely done, lab!

Answer (score 1):

Also using Euler's theorem

$$x^{\varphi(9)}\equiv 1 \pmod 9$$ or

$$x^{6}\equiv 1 \pmod 9$$ therefore

$9 | (x^3-1)(x^3+1)$ and since $3$ cannot divide both factors,
$9 |(x^3+1)$ or $9 | (x^3-1)$

Answer (score 0):

If $3$ does not divide $x$, then exactly one of the following is true: $x \equiv -4,x \equiv -2,x \equiv -1,x \equiv 1,x \equiv 2,x \equiv 4$, where all the equivalences are mod 9. (I've removed the cases $x \equiv -3,x \equiv 0,x \equiv 3$; why is $x$ divisible by $3$ in each of these cases?) What happens when you cube each of these cases?